# db2 sql partitioning

Tags: sql, db2

The issue I am having has to do with not being able to show different OrderDate for the same Unit

```
Unit    OrderDate     ShipDate   ReceiptDate  
Robot 20160101       20160102   20160103   
Robot 20160102       20160103   20160104 
Robot 20160103       20160104   20160105
```

What is happening instead is that it is showing the same OrderDate for all three records.

```
Unit    OrderDate     ShipDate   ReceiptDate  
Robot 20160101       20160102   20160103     
Robot 20160101       20160103   20160104   
Robot 20160101       20160104   20160105
```

```
SELECT salesorder.unitid "Unit",
       max(salesorder.eventdate) "OrderDate",
       max(salesdelivery.eventdate) "ShipDate",
       max(salesreceipt.eventdate) "ReceiptDate"
FROM (
  SELECT eventdate,
         unitid
  FROM sales
  WHERE event = 'ORDER'
    AND eventdate > '2015-12-31'
    AND eventdate < '2016-02-01'
) salesorder
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT eventdate,
           unitid
    FROM sales
    WHERE event = 'SHIP'
      AND eventdate > '2015-12-31'
      AND eventdate < '2016-02-01'
  ) salesdelivery ON salesorder.unitid = salesdelivery.unitid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT eventdate,
           unitid
    FROM sales
    WHERE event = 'RECEIPT'
      AND eventdate > '2015-12-31'
      AND eventdate < '2016-02-01'
  ) salesreceipt ON salesdelivery.unitid = salesreceipt.unitid
WHERE salesdelivery.eventdate > salesorder.eventdate
  AND salesreceipt.eventdate > salesdelivery.eventdate
  AND salesorder.unitid = '001'
GROUP BY salesorder.unitid
```

Comment: The "output" you have shown doesn't seem to match the query. How do you get three identical values of `salesorder.unitid` if you group by that column?

Comment: I'm guessing you actually want to group by salesorder.eventdate